# Object creation in python and separation from other objects

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, class, oop, object

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = A()
```

When we instantiate a class, what happens in the background between the call A() and the call to the constructor?

Also, when we create more than one object of a class, how is it ensured that both of these objects are referring to different memory locations?

Edit: Well, after further exploration, I found the right answer here in this article. 
https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/10/03/understanding-python-class-instantiation/

This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class below, the `__init__` is called the constructor and is called when you instantiate the object of the class.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print("creating")

a = A()
#creating
```

When you create two objects of the same class, both refer to different memory locations as you can see below

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print(a1)
print(a2)
<__main__.A object at 0x108ea6f98>
<__main__.A object at 0x108ea6f28>
```

Both objects are referring to different memory locations `0x108ea6f98` and `0x108ea6f28`

Further more you can check the[id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of the objects  which os different as well

```
print(id(a1))
print(id(a2))
#4529184552
#4529329264
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class will create even if you just type this..

```
class A: 
    pass

a = A()
```

`__init__` is like a constructor it'll call when you make class instance.

---

Now when you make more than one object of a same class they all are saved separately in the memory.

**For ex**

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
b = A()

print( a == b )
print( a, b )
```

**Output**

```
False
<__main__.A object at 0x1049a4898> <__main__.A object at 0x1049a4710>
```

When you print the first statement it'll print `False`.
If you compare both objects of `a` and `b` from second print statement you can tell that they're not same.

Comment: I understand the constructor and syntax of the class.
But my question was how exactly the creation of object takes place?

This question was asked to me in an interview so searching for the answer.